# How to get pre-order package rewards?

Tags: the-secret-world

I bought a pre-order pack / registered the key before a set date, and am supposed to get some stuff for it  (e.g. Screaming Demon ring, cat, dog, etc.). But I cannot seem to find it in my inventory! Where do I get my rewards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log in to your character, open the in-game shop (!) (default key ".") and then use the first menu entry on the left. There they are, your items - you can now "buy" them for 0 points. After buying, they appear in your inventory.

You can do this once per character, I'm told.

Comment: Your note is wrong, the items are only claimable once per character. That means if you get the ring for character foo, and you create a character bar, you can do the same and claim the ring for him.

Comment: I can also confirm the items are one-per-character.

Comment: Thank you, I'll correct this - the information given by funcom semt to state differently, probably misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Worth noting that you cannot do this until after you've made it to Kingsmouth town - so follow the intro until you get there before complaining that the store isn't accessible.